# Open-source password manager for OS X

Tags: macos, ios, password, open-source

I am looking for a password manager that works on iOS and OS X (and syncs passwords between those) that is open-source.

Currently, I use mSecure on my iPhone, but I would like to switch to an open-source option.

Comment: What have you researched?

Comment: I have been reading about gnu-pw-mgr here https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-pw-mgr/ 

However I find it way too complicated for my needs. Although it seems to be pretty secure, that I like, but still too complicated.

Comment: IMHO Just use 1Password.

Comment: Also, here are seven (enough? :D) http://venturebeat.com/2015/10/13/7-open-source-password-managers-to-try-now-that-logmein-owns-lastpass/

Answer (score 4):

Most notably [KeePassX](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx) (port of KeePass) is released under the terms of the [GNU General Public License](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).

It doesn't have a direct port to iOS, but the database format is standard across KeePass-family and you can use another client for iOS, like [MiniKeePass](https://github.com/MiniKeePass/MiniKeePass) (also GNU General Public License).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use apple's iCloud KeyChain? it is available on both OS and makes everything by itself... You can manage all the passwords from the KeyChain Access Application in OSX...

Comment: Oscar, iCloud Keychain is *definitely* not open-source.

Comment: Well, that's not so black-and-white. Keychain API is public and Keychain Access application itself [is open sourced](http://opensource.apple.com//source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-27723/) (OS X version). In result there are 3rd party apps allowing access to the iCloud Keychain.

Comment: @JohnRamos He just want to keep passwords between apple devices, why not use apple default password keeper?

Comment: @Oscar_sgc I honestly don't know why Saul would want that, but the question is clearly looking for an **Open-source** password manager, see the title. So your answer doesn't work given that Apple does not publish their iCloud Keychain code for open sourcing.